# Full node resyncs every time we 'attach to tangle' and it take a long time

Tags: syncing

Full node resyncs every time we 'attach to tangle' and this takes a long time.
We have a network of full nodes which need to process work in parallel and the resyncing is crippling their productivity.
What can we do about this?

Comment: Please provide more information, because this question is too broad.